# Need help to complete my regexp to find a required * when string length is less than 6 and pattern matching when length is 6

Tags: angular, regex, typescript

I've been at this for a couple days and I have managed to get things working as best I can.
The requirements changed on me this morning where the value can now be less than 6 characters long.

(Removed) Here is a link to my RegEx101.com test

This is for use on an Angular applications Angular Material field Validator.

**Negative Lookbehind is not supported.**

```
(?![*]{2,})(?!^[*][a-zA-Z])(?!([*|a|b|A|B]|[0-9]){1,5}$)(^[*|a|b|A|B]([*](?![*])|[0-9]){1,5}$)
```

My above pattern can find all valid values as long as the length is 6.

I need to be able to find all valid values where a * is present in any position when the length is less than 6.

```
Following would be valid which I can find with my RegEx
A12*4*
A*23*5
A123*5
*123*5

Following would be valid but my RegEx does not have logic 
*
*1
*1*
A*
A*2
A*2*
A1*3
A1*3*
A12*4

Examples of invalid entries: <Any ** entry> - <Any * A-Z character> - <Any value longer than 6>
**
*A1234
*123456
```

I've read many posts here on the forum but am not finding a solution for this.

A huge thanks to @The Fourth Bird for all their help.

Updated LINK: [RegEx101.com demo](https://regex101.com/r/omsG5I/3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use 2 negative lookaheads to make sure that `**` and `*[A-Z]` is not present. Then match 1-6 times any char of `[a-zA-Z0-9*]`

```
^(?![a-zA-Z0-9*]*\*\*)(?![a-zA-Z0-9*]*\*[A-Z])(?=[a-zA-Z0-9*]*\*)[a-zA-Z0-9*]{1,6}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?![a-zA-Z0-9*]*\*\*)` Negative lookahead, assert not `**`
- `(?![a-zA-Z0-9*]*\*[A-Z])` Negative lookahead, assert not `*` followed by `[A-Z]`
- `(?=[a-zA-Z0-9*]*\*)` Positive lookahead, assert at least one `*`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9*]{1,6}` Match 1-6 times any of the listed
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kOstY6/1)

---

To match only ABD instead of A-Z and the string should not start with a digit, using a case insensitive match:

```
^(?![ABD0-9*]*\*\*)(?![ABD0-9*]*\*[ABD])(?=[ABD0-9*]*\*)[ABD*][ABD0-9*]{0,5}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6RPfDR/1)

Comment: Question, regarding the pattern [a-zA-Z0-9*], I have specific letters I need to check for and numbers, what is the correct format to write that lets say if A,B,D,* and 0-9 are the only valid characters? [a|b|c|A|B|C|0-9|*] ?????

Comment: Then you can use `[abdABD0-9]` or use `[ABD0-9]` with a case insensitive match.

Comment: See `^(?![ABD0-9*]*\*\*)(?![ABD0-9*]*\*[ABD])(?=[ABD0-9*]*\*)[ABD0-9*]{1,6}$`  https://regex101.com/r/GnOpyU/1

Comment: I've been playing in the RegEx101 with your demo and it is working just as I needed. Thank you so much for your help as it solved my problem.

Comment: 1 Last thing, I noticed that a value that starts with number that contains a * comes up as valid and so validation is to ensure that 1st character of string must be a character and not a number when * is in use. This seems to handle it (?!^[0-9])

Comment: @Elijah That would work. You could also  make the first char not match the digits followed by repeating the character class 0-5 times like `^(?![ABD0-9*]*\*\*)(?![ABD0-9*]*\*[ABD])(?=[ABD0-9*]*\*)[ABD*][ABD0-9*]{0,5}$` https://regex101.com/r/6RPfDR/1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222597/discussion-between-elijah-and-the-fourth-bird).

Comment: Latest updated regexp https://regex101.com/r/omsG5I/3